# Authenticity of Hanuman searching for Rama's ring and realizing the nature of time

Tags: ramayana, hanuman, time, yama

There is a story over the internet and the story goes like this

> When the time came for the departure of Rama, Yama says to Rama that
> he cannot able to come to earth because of the presence of Hanuman.
> Then Rama throws his ring somewhere and asks Hanuman to bring it back.
> While searching for it, Hanuman realizes that time is cyclic in nature by
> watching many rings of Rama. In between Rama departs from Earth.

The story seems to be not authentic. But is there any Ramayana that contains a story similar to this?

Comment: This story is printed by many newspaper and other media, I still coudlnt find any source in padma purana yet.

Answer (score 3):

This story is printed by many newspaper and other media, I still couldn't find any source in Padma Purana yet.

Instead as per the sources given at this [URL](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/padmapurana27.html) , the story of termination of Shree Rama Avatara in Padma Purana is different.

> Taking a hint from Shri Rama, Vibishana, Sugriva, Jambavan, Hanuman,
> Neela, Nala, Sushena and Nishada Raja Guha arrived. Shatrughna
> performed the coronatation of his sons at Ayodhya. The rest of them
> said that they would not like to stay back on Earth in the abscence of
> Rama even for a moment. But Rama asked Vibhishana to continue in power
> at Lanka for long time and instructed Hanuman to continue on Earth
> forever to sustain the message of Shi Rama. The rest of them
> accompanied Shri Rama into the Sacred Sarayu River. Bharat,
> Shatrughna, and all the citizens of Ayodhya along with their wives,
> Mantris, Servants, Vedikas, Brahmanas, the nearby animals, birds, and
> all other Beings who accompanied Shri Rama never looked back. As Shri
> Rama went deep into the River, Lord Brahma, Devas, Rishis and all
> Celestial Beings extolled Raghunatha even as He took the Huge Form of
> Maha Vishnu with his four hands along with Bharata as Shankha,
> Shatrughna as Chakra, as also Gada with Sri Devi and Bhu Devi beside
> Him.

Answer (score 3):

As asked in this question, there is a similar story.

**It is found in Sri Parashara Samhita-Hanuman charitam.**

After the war with Ravana, lord hanuman once came to visit lord Rama.
Lord Rama told Lord Hanuman to bring his ring which he gave to lord Bramha.
(This was the same ring which Lord Hanuman gave to mata Sita in Ashok vatika.)

Lord Hanuman went to Brahmaloka and asked lord brahma to give the ring.
Lord Brahma didn't give it because he worshipped it daily thinking about Shri Rama.

Lord Hanuman became very angry and showed his universal form.On seeing him like this, everyone including the sages and gods who were present with Brahma deva got afraid of him.

Then, Maharshi Sanatakumara advised Brahma deva to give the ring to lord Hanuman and hence, Brahma deva worshipped Vayuputra to calm him and led him to the place(It was a lake) which was having the ring.

**On reaching there, Lord Anjaneya saw not one, but many rings of lord Rama.
He was surprised.
He could not find the real ring and afraid of breaching the order of his lord, returned to Ayodhya.**
On reaching and meeting his lord, he narrated his experience to ShriRama.

**ShriRama then explained him that in every kalpa, he gives the ring to Lord Brahma and Brahma deva worships the rings as though he is worshipping him(ShriRama).**

After explaining this to Lord Hanuman, he told him to go to Satyaloka again, and bring one of the rings for Mata Seeta.

He again went to Brahmaloka, took the ring and gave it to Mata Seeta.

Source: [Chapter 53](http://www.jayahanumanji.com/?p=2959) and [Chapter 54](http://www.jayahanumanji.com/?p=2961) of Parashara Samhita.