# how did yamaraj sabha had 100 Dhritrashta , 100 Bhimas and 200 Bhishma?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, name, bhishma, yama

From Mahabharata, Sabha Parva -

> *"a hundred kings of the name of Dhritarashtra, eighty kings of the name of Janamejaya; a hundred monarchs called Brahmadatta, and a hundred kings of the name of Iri; more than two hundred Bhishmas, and also a hundred Bhimas; a hundred Prativindhyas, a hundred Nagas, and a hundred Palasas, and a hundred called Kasa and Kusa; that king of kings Santanu, and thy father Pandu."*

**How can that be possible** . I have heard the story about lord hanuman going to patala-lok and seeing the mountain of rings of lord Rama depicting the many Rama births and how many times they have had done this play of rings . IS it similar here, are these dhritrashtra and bhimas of different kalpa.?

The chapter mentions Kirtivirya arjuna ( sahastra bahu ) as well, wouldn't he already turn into sudarshan if his avatar was over.?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/40597/authenticity-of-hanuman-searching-for-ramas-ring-and-realizing-the-nature-of-ti

Comment: sahasra (1000) bahu, not sahastra bahu.

Answer (score 1):

There were other people with the name of Bhima in the clan of King Bharata that was not Pandava Bhima.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01095.htm

> They were Dushmanta, Sura, Bhima, Pravasu, and Vasu.

> And they were named Kakshasena and Ugrasena, and Chitrasena endued with great energy, and Indrasena and Sushena and Bhimasena.

There was another Chandravanshi Dhritarashtra who was not the father of Duryodhana.

> And they were all proficient in morality and profit and were kind to all creatures. Among them Dhritarashtra became king. And Dhritarashtra had eight sons, viz., Kundika, Hasti, Vitarka, Kratha the fifth, Havihsravas, Indrabha, and Bhumanyu the invincible, and Dhritarashtra had many grandsons, of whom three only were famous.

---

Bhima was also one of the 1000 names of Lord Vishnu.

https://www.saibaba.us/texts/vishnusahasranama.pdf

> Atula-sharabho bheemah sama-yagno havir-harih |

There were many people with the names of Bhima and Dhritarashtra.