# Cyclic nature of time in Ramayana

Tags: ramayana, time

Many scriptures in Sanathan dharma say about the cyclic nature of time in many places.

Consider some of the excerpts

From Mahabharata

> **Hundreds and thousands of great-Kalpas, hundreds and thousands of
> Creation and Dissolutions**, O king of kings, have been over and have
> become incidents of the past.
>
> [[Section 340, Mokshadharma Parva, Santi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c039.htm#fn_255)

From Yoga Vasistha

> Sir, you have seen the many changes of the world, and have been
> experienced in all things in the **repeated course of creations**; must be
> best able to tell me the wonders that you have witnessed during the
> revolution of ages.
>
> [[27, Chapter 21: Explanation of the cause of the crow’s longevity, Nirvana Prakarana, Yoga Vasistha]](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-sanskrit/d/doc263003.html)

Is there any similar mentioning in Valmiki Ramayana that implies the cyclic nature of time in terms of creation and dissolution?

Comment: Yes the story about the search of Hanuman of Rama's ring.

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/40597/authenticity-of-hanuman-searching-for-ramas-ring-and-realizing-the-nature-of-ti

Answer (score -1):

**In the Uttara-kanda of the Valmiki Ramayan there's a reference to cyclic nature of universe.**

Ravana goes to the netherworlds, and meets the asura king MahaBali.

Bali describes to Ravana the glories of god Vishnu as follows -

> [Chapter 23a](https://archive.org/details/ShrimadValmikiRamayan-SanskritTextWithHindiTranslation-DpSharma10/ShrimadValmikiRamayan-SktHindi-DpSharmaVol09-UttaraKandaPurvardh1927/page/n253/mode/1up?view=theater)<sup>1</sup>, Uttar-Kanda, Valmiki Ramayan
>
> न त्वं वेद न चैवाहं भूतभव्यभवत्प्रभुः ।
>  कलिलश्चैवप कालश्च
> सर्वभृतापहारकः ॥ ३६ ॥
>  **लोकत्रयस्य सर्वस्य हर्ता सृष्टा तथैव च ।
>
> संहरत्येष भृतानि स्थावराणि चराणि च ॥ ३७ ॥
>  पुनश्च सृजते सर्वेमनाद्यतं
> महेश्वरः ।** 
>  इष्टं चैव हि दत्तं च हुतं चैव निशाचरः ॥ ३८ ॥
>  सर्वमेव हि
> लोकेशो धाता गोप्ता न संशयः । 
>  नैवंविघं महद्भूतं विद्यते भुवनत्रये ॥ ३९
> ॥
>
> > - 36 to 39. Neither you nor I know Him; He is the Lord of the past, present and future, He is Time, He is the Kali Yuga, He overthrows all
> >   beings; **He is the Creator and Destroyer of the Three Worlds and of all
> >   animate and inanimate things; that great God of all Gods creates and
> >   re-creates the universe again and again for ever**. O Nightranger, He is
> >   the Dispenser of the fruits of sacrifices, gifts and oblations, verily
> >   He is the Creator and Preserver of the entire Universe, there is none
> >   in the Three Worlds comparable with Him in majesty and glory.
>
> [English Translation](https://archive.org/details/The.Ramayana.of.Valmiki.by.Hari.Prasad.Shastri/page/440/mode/1up?view=theater) by Shri Hari Prasad Shastri

---

Comment: Notes on interpolations is not needed as OP specifically doesn't ask them. Please refer [When is it acceptable to caution the reader of disputes as to the origin of a text or passage?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1010/3500)

Comment: Actually, I'm just describing how the publisher has printed the text. If you click [here, the Hindi Translation version](https://archive.org/details/ShrimadValmikiRamayan-SanskritTextWithHindiTranslation-DpSharma10/ShrimadValmikiRamayan-SktHindi-DpSharmaVol09-UttaraKandaPurvardh1927/page/n244/mode/1up?view=theater), the page open on the said chapter which is Titled as  'Prakshipta Prathama Sarga'. Similarly in [the English Translation version](https://archive.org/details/The.Ramayana.of.Valmiki.by.Hari.Prasad.Shastri/page/438/mode/1up?view=theater),.... (1/3)

Comment: .... Shastri ji notes in the starting of the chapter, that _some commentators (for instance Govindaraja in his commentary called [Bhushan](https://archive.org/details/ValmikiRamayana-UttaraKandaWithGovindarajaCommentary/page/n63/mode/2up)) on VR consider the following five chapters as interpolation_ and it's printed in the book in the same manner.... (2/3)

Comment: I'm just clarifying things. In case, in future a certain user pops up saying where did you get these verses I can't find them on the [Wikisource website](https://sa.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%89%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A8%E0%A5%A9) or ....

Comment: .... the [English Version by MN Dutt](https://archive.org/details/TheRamayanaUttaraKandam/page/n86/mode/1up?view=theater) on in the [Gita Press Gorakhpur's version](https://archive.org/details/wg966/page/n1517/mode/2up).  Therefore, I'm of the view, that it's pertinent to make remarks as intended by the original publisher of the material we're copying from.

These passages are not published by all Publishers, so it may get confusing for a novice to make sense of anything. Thus, I appended with appropriate remarks, as and exactly how found in the Original publication I have copied from. (3/3)

Comment: If someone asks, you can mention this. As of now, it is not needed, Now, people may argue on interpolations. Interpolations are very subjective. Those meta discussions suggest to not mention notes on interpolations, unless and otherwise explicitly asked in questions. Or You can add name of Publisher and manuscript name instead using word "Interpolation".